In what sense is Christ's divinity contained in the Eucharist?

In the most blessed sacrament of the Eucharist "the body and blood, together with the soul and divinity, of our Lord Jesus Christ and, therefore, the whole Christ is truly, really, and substantially contained." (CCC 1374).

How can God be contained in a material object? Obviously God can give certain objects and places a quality of holiness, but I assume the Eucharist goes beyond that. Obviously God cannot be matter, but how then does the Eucharist differ from other matter?  Does the Eucharist differ from say, a church in kind, or is God's presence just much stronger in it?

Try to reflect on the Mystery of Incarnation. "The Highest Heaven cannot contain God whom She carried in Her womb. " (Book of Kings) or you can try E=mC2, Eucharist = Mary's flesh and blood x Christ humanity and Christ divinity (C2-Christ two natures". See, even Albert Einstein famous equation is connected to the Eucharist. Why? Because Jesus symbolizes the Sun, on which Einstein formulated E=mC2. -Ave!

Those answers are about how it can be Christ's body, whereas my question is in what sense God is contained in it. Perhaps my question is about the incarnation in general.

The duplicate is about the 'Presence' not the body. Divinity is part of Presence.

@NigelJ No, his question is meaningful. Some might take "real presence" only to mean "body and blood" and not connect to the idea of "divinity" so clarifying on that part could be beneficial.

@wmasse If you don't know what your question is, then it's not really reasonable to expect anyone else to! One problem is that the sacrament does not "contain" God. It is God.
